# Cambiar estilo con JS de visibility: hidden a visibility: visible -- Problema

Tags: javascript, html5, css

Buenas, tengo una webapp que se conecta a una API y saca una serie de datos.

Hasta ahí bien, todo funciona.

El problema viene cuando pongo a todos los divs (o la mayoria) en visibility: hidden con la intencion de volverlos a hacerlos visibles cuando se cumpla un IF concreto.

Ahí viene el problema. Se vuelven visibles, pero no hay ningun dato... Y me está volviendo loco.

Teóricamente lo de visibility: hidden; sigue comportandose igual no? Deberían estar ahí los datos!

Un poco de codigo: (ATENCION: En la caja principal, no lo pongo en hidden, sino que le cambio el height de 700 a 100 y luego lo paso a 700 again)

CSS

```
#full{

width: 450px;
height: 140px;
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 20px;
visibility: hidden;
```

JS

```
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {


            document.getElementById("box").style.height = "700px";
            document.getElementById("full").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("logobox").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("logobox img").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("infobox").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("reposBox").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("iconsBox").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("reposFull").style.visibility = "visible";


            json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código html?

Comment: Por favor revisa el siguiente link: [ask] o tendremos que cerrar tu pregunta